# Prevent json/pure from loading in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems, require

I'm writing a Rails application, using the 'json' gem, and its behavior where it can switch between the 'json/pure' and 'json/ext' implementations is causing problems. Specifically, sometimes a gem introduces a line like

```
require 'json/pure'
```

When that happens, JSON.parser and JSON.generator switch to the slow, ruby-based version globally. Then every call to JSON.parse and JSON.generate are slow.

I want to avoid the situation where a changing gem dependency, unbeknownst to me, suddenly makes my site much slower. How can I prevent 'json/pure' from ever being loaded, enforce 'json/ext' usage, or otherwise prevent this problem in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent json/pure from being loaded, this works:

```
require 'json/ext'
JSON.freeze
```

You have to run this before json/pure is required.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work in your case, and the cure could be worse than the disease:

```
module Kernel
  alias old_require require

  def require(path)
    if path =='json/pure'
       # do something appropriate
    else
       old_require path
    end
  end
end
```

I've monkey patched require when I wanted to benchmark the performance of various startup bottlenecks in our rails app.  Perhaps you could see why these gems are trying to require 'json/pure' and perhaps stop it another way.

I find gem source code to be generally very readable.  bundle open  does the trick for me.

Comment: You might want to change `super` to `old_require(path)`

Comment: I can stop it when I detect it - the issue is that a lot of people are working on the code base and I would like to programmatically prevent people from using json/pure in the future.